# Does kernel have its own stack (not kernel thread)? And how to read the `vm_map` structure of kernel in FreeBSD?

Tags: memory, memory-management, kernel, driver, freebsd

I need to find all the kernel-owned memory regions under FreeBSD x86_64. One option is to traverse `vm_map_entry` and find the `start_addr` and `end_addr` as `K0-K1`, `K2-K3`, `K4-K5`, `K7-K8`.

As I noticed, there is no stack in these areas. I believe kernel has a very limited stack, but how to find its address?

Also, how to know which `vm_map` is kernel's. 
I.e., how to write a kernel module to read the information of kernel `vm_map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not answer your question directly, but take a look at the crashdump code, ie sys/kern/kern_dump.c.  It basically does what you need - it dumps kernel-owned parts of physical memory.

As for stacks - kernel does not have a single stack; every thread has a kernel stack, and userland threads *also* have a userland stack.  Kernel stacks are indeed limited, to KSTACK_PAGES, which is usually 4 (in pages, not bytes).